# 2 Heroku App Same database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, heroku

I have 2 meteor apps that I would deploy to heroku. However, I would want these 2 apps to use the same mongodb database (MLab) and not sure how to configure. Anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how to do this in Heroku, but it's as easy as setting both instances to refer to the same Mongo database in your configs.

Answer (score 0):

Provide (same) MONGO_URL config variable in settings dashboard for both apps on heroku. You can get the url of your db in mlab dashboard, starts with;
mongodb://username:pass@...